# Could not create path to save downloaded file - Ionic iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to release an application written in Ionic Cordova but I face a problem with one of the functionalities of the app. Especially, there is a button where you download a file which works perfect in the android version, but in iOS I get this error:

> FileTransferError {
>       body = "Could not create path to save downloaded file: The file \U201c\U201d couldn\U2019t be saved.";
>       code = 1;
>       "http_status" = 200;
>       source = "https://player.vimeo.com/external/221750072.sd.mp4?s=4dd5a5319a2484a715c54f58ef5b0e53&profile_id=165&download=1";
>       target = "null.CHURCHOF%20SAINT%20JOHN.mp4"; } File Transfer Error: Could not create path to save downloaded file: The file “”
>   couldn’t be saved.

Comment: What's the path ? "The file “” couldn’t be saved." seems that the path is wrong (no file name set)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you making the destination path? It seems that some propertie you are using is `null`, so you should modify it in order to get a valid destination path. For instance, I use for this purpose an structure like:

```
var destPath = (cordova.file.externalDataDirectory || cordova.file.dataDirectory) 
               + "path_to_destination"
```

And then the fileTransfer plugin:

```
var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.download(url, destPath, success, error, true);
```